# Put collapsible panel inside a listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to put a collapsible panel that contains a listview, inside another listview.  I've almost got it but can't get the header of the panel to format correctly and it's not "lined up" in proportion with the other listview items.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
            <li role="heading" data-role="list-divider">Options
            </li>
            <li data-theme="a">
                <a href="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="c" data-native-menu = "false">Create Map</a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="a">
                <a href="#" data-transition="slide" data-theme="c" data-native-menu = "false">Close Map</a>
            </li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" id="" data-collapsed="false">
                    <h4>Add Map</h4>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">                
                    <li data-theme="a">
                        <a href="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="c" data-native-menu = "false">By ZipCode</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="a">
                        <a href="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="c" data-native-menu = "false">By Street #</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </div>
           <li data-theme="a">
                <a href="" data-transition="slide" data-theme="c" data-native-menu = "false">View Map</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/UsZUU/

**UPDATE**

I found an example online here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m6zVq/ which pointed me in the right direction.  My only issue now is if I set `data-inset="true"` in the first `<ul>` instead of false, then the background of the `<div>` that's collapsible, expands past the rest of the listview.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/Skjyf/ (sorry, I don't know how to update my first fiddle and save it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Is this what you wanted to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/34LJM/

I have added this css to your example:

```
.ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-content {
    margin: 0 0 !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.